# Soft edged images in GDI+

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Im trying to convert the code found here: [soft-edged-images-in-gdi](https://danbystrom.se/2008/08/24/soft-edged-images-in-gdi/), to c++. Its used to create bitmaps with rounded corners and soft edges.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

#include <gdiplus.h> 
#include <gdipluspath.h>
#include <gdiplusimaging.h>
#include <gdipluspixelformats.h >
#include <wingdi.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "gdiplus.lib")



using namespace Gdiplus;
GraphicsPath* createRoundRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int radius)
{
    GraphicsPath* gp = new GraphicsPath;

    if (radius == 0)
        gp->AddRectangle(Rect(x, y, width, height));
    else
    {
        gp->AddLine(x + radius, y, x + width - radius, y);
        gp->AddArc(x + width - radius, y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        gp->AddLine(x + width, y + radius, x + width, y + height - radius);
        gp->AddArc(x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
        gp->AddLine(x + width - radius, y + height, x + radius, y + height);
        gp->AddArc(x, y + height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        gp->AddLine(x, y + height - radius, x, y + radius);
        gp->AddArc(x, y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        gp->CloseFigure();
    }
    return gp;
}



Brush* createFluffyBrush(GraphicsPath* gp, float* blendPositions, float* blendFactors, INT count, INT* in_out_count)
{
    PathGradientBrush* pgb = new PathGradientBrush(gp);

    //Blend blend = new Blend();
    //blend.Positions = blendPositions;
    //blend.Factors = blendFactors;
    //pgb->Blend = blend;

    /* count:
        Type: INT
        Integer that specifies the number of elements in the blendFactors array.
        This is the same as the number of elements in the blendPositions array.
    */
    pgb->SetBlend(blendFactors, blendPositions, count);
    pgb->SetCenterColor(Color::White);

    // in_out_count:
    /*
        Type: INT*
        Pointer to an integer that, on input, specifies the number of Color objects in the colors array.
        If the method succeeds, this parameter, on output, receives the number of surround colors set.
        If the method fails, this parameter does not receive a value.
    */
    pgb->SetSurroundColors(new  Color(Color::Black), in_out_count);
    return pgb;
}



enum ChannelARGB
{
    Blue = 0,
    Green = 1,
    Red = 2,
    Alpha = 3
};



void transferOneARGBChannelFromOneBitmapToAnother(Bitmap* source, Bitmap* dest, ChannelARGB sourceChannel, ChannelARGB destChannel)
{
    if ((source->GetWidth() != dest->GetWidth())
        || (source->GetHeight() != dest->GetHeight())
        )
    {
        //throw  ArgumentException();
    };

    Rect* r = new Rect(0, 0, source->GetWidth(), source->GetHeight());
    BitmapData* bdSrc = new BitmapData;
    source->LockBits(r, ImageLockMode::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, bdSrc); //PixelFormat(Format32bppArgb)
    BitmapData* bdDst = new BitmapData;
    dest->LockBits(r, ImageLockMode::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, bdDst);
    try
    {
        byte* bpSrc = (byte*)bdSrc->Scan0;//ToPointer()
        byte* bpDst = (byte*)bdDst->Scan0;
        bpSrc += (int)sourceChannel;
        bpDst += (int)destChannel;
        for (int i = r->Height * r->Width; i > 0; i--)
        {
            *bpDst = *bpSrc;
            bpSrc += 4;
            bpDst += 4;
        }

    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {

    }

    source->UnlockBits(bdSrc);
    dest->UnlockBits(bdDst);
}



//////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////
//Bitmap* bmpFluffy = new Bitmap(bmpOriginal);
Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmpFluffy = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"picture.png", false);

Rect r(0, 0, bmpFluffy->GetWidth(), bmpFluffy->GetHeight());
Bitmap* bmpMask = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
Graphics* g = Graphics::FromImage(bmpMask);
GraphicsPath* path = createRoundRect(
    r.X, r.Y,
    r.Width, r.Height,
    min(r.Width, r.Height) / 5);;

int in_out_count = 1;
Brush brush = createFluffyBrush(
    path,
    new float[] { 0.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f },
    new float[] { 0.0f, 0.95f, 1.0f }, 3, &in_out_count);
{

    g->FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color::Black), r); //Brush  to solidbrush
    g->SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingMode::SmoothingModeHighQuality);
    g->FillPath(&brush, path);
    transferOneARGBChannelFromOneBitmapToAnother(
        bmpMask,
        bmpFluffy,
        ChannelARGB::Blue,
        ChannelARGB::Alpha);
}
```

I have no experience with `.net`, and im not sure if the code has been converted correctly, i wonder if someone could take a look at it.

Current im getting error only at this line: `Brush brush = createFluffyBrush(`

`no suitable constructor exist to convert from "Gdiplus::Brush *" to "Gdiplus::Brush"`

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Stack Overflow isn't a *"here's my code, please fix, kthnx"* service.

Comment: I havent an example, the example is the code.

Comment: The link provides instructions on how to create a [mcve]. You'll find your experience with Stack Overflow will be much more pleasant if you decide to put work into it.

Answer (score 0):

createFluffyBrush return a pointer to Brush,

so you should use :

```
Brush brush = *createFluffyBrush(...)
```

or (better here ?)

```
Brush * brush = createFluffyBrush(...)
```

Comment: Both options are wrong. The code is transferring ownership and neither one encodes that. Either have `createFluffyBrush` return a `unique_ptr`, or simply return a `Brush` by value.

Comment: Hi, none of your examples compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the `new` operator in modern C++. Gdiplus is kind of old, so you can keep using pointers and `new` in some places, for example to declare `Gdiplus::Bitmap*` object. For structures such as `Gdiplus::GraphicsPath` you can use pass by reference, that's usually the easiest and safest method.

To draw rounded images, get the rounded path, clip the region, then use anti-aliasing to draw a rounded rectangle over that image. Example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

void GetRoundRectPath(Gdiplus::GraphicsPath& path, Gdiplus::Rect rc, int diameter)
{
    if (diameter > rc.Width) diameter = rc.Width;
    if (diameter > rc.Height) diameter = rc.Height;

    int dx = rc.Width - diameter;
    int dy = rc.Height - diameter;

    Gdiplus::Rect tl(rc.X, rc.Y, diameter, diameter);  //top-left
    Gdiplus::Rect tr = tl; tr.Offset(dx, 0);  //top-right
    Gdiplus::Rect br = tl; br.Offset(dx, dy); //bottom-right
    Gdiplus::Rect bl = tl; bl.Offset(0, dy);  //bottom-left
    
    path.Reset();
    path.AddArc(br, 0,   90);
    path.AddArc(bl, 90,  90);
    path.AddArc(tl, 180, 90);
    path.AddArc(tr, 270, 90);
    path.CloseFigure();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static Gdiplus::Image* img = nullptr;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        img = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"test.jpg");
        if (img->GetLastStatus() != 0)
            MessageBox(0, L"no image", 0, 0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        if (!img)
            break;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
       
        Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
        Gdiplus::GraphicsPath path;
        Gdiplus::Rect rc{ 10, 10, (int)img->GetWidth(), (int)img->GetHeight() };

        GetRoundRectPath(path, rc, 32);
        Gdiplus::Region rgn(&path);
        g.SetClip(&rgn);
        g.DrawImage(img, rc);

        rgn.MakeInfinite();
        g.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
        Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color::White, 2.0F);
        g.DrawPath(&pen, &path);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        if(img) delete img;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, PSTR, INT)
{
    ULONG_PTR token;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput tmp;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token, &tmp, NULL);

    WNDCLASS wndClass {0};
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndClass.hInstance = hinst;
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndClass.lpszClassName = L"test";
    RegisterClass(&wndClass);

    CreateWindow(wndClass.lpszClassName, L"Test", WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        100, 100, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hinst, nullptr);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to reach the result seen in the picture3 at the link i post?

Comment: I tried using your code directly into an image, but it saved a image completely weird https://pastebin.com/Bu0bJfTz, the image : https://i.imgur.com/eHb7UN9.png, whats is the first two 10 in `Gdiplus::Rect rc2{ 10, 10, (int)img2->GetWidth(), (int)img2->GetHeight() };`

Comment: The question was not about saving the file. `10,10` is the top-left coordinate for the image, randomly chosen.

Comment: Very helpful not being able to save the file.